# Avoid round off error in exponential calculation

Tags: math, rounding, numerical, exponential

Due to rounding error cannot get ratio between two numbers:
`Ratio=exp(x)/(exp(x)+exp(y))` such that `x=-1.11e4` and `y=-1.12e4`.
Any mathematical or computational trick to do?

Comment: exp(-1.11e4) gives zero due to rounding error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about some mathematical manipulation in log-space...

```
R = exp(x)/[exp(x)+exp(y)]
log(R) = log[exp(x)] - log[exp(x)+exp(y)]
       = log[exp(x)] - log[exp(x)*(1+exp(y)/exp(x))]
       = log[exp(x)] - log[exp(x)*(1+exp(y-x)]
       = log[exp(x)] - log[exp(x)] - log[(1+exp(y-x))]
       = - log[(1+exp(y-x))]
```

Now, `exp(y-x)` should be a reasonable number, so you can calculate that easily.  Then convert back to normal space using `R = exp(log(R))`.

If that *still doesn't work*, you can actually [taylor expand the last line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions):

```
log[(1+z)] ~ 1 + z^2/2 - z^3/3 ...
```

for small `z`, in this case `z = exp(y-x)`.

Comment: Can you double-check your working - I think there might be a small mistake here: `= log[exp(x)] - log[exp(x)*(1+exp(x)/exp(y))]` - this should probably be `= log[exp(x)] - log[exp(x)*(1+exp(y)/exp(x))]` ?

Comment: There might be a typo in line 3 it should read as pointed out by Paul.

Comment: I was also missing a minus sign... yikes.  Not enough coffee today

Comment: Thanks DilithiumMatrix that is very helpful.

Comment: Yes, I think you're there now, and of course the final result is just `exp(- log[(1+exp(y-x))])` == `1 / (1 + exp(y - x))`. It didn't really need the round trip into log-land and back again! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can simplify it like this:

```
R = exp(x) / (exp(x) + exp(y))
  = exp(x) / (exp(x) * (1 + exp(y) / exp(x)))
  =      1 / (1 + exp(y) / exp(x))
  =      1 / (1 + exp(y - x))
```

(This is the same result as derived by [DiltihiumMatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/230468/dilithiummatrix), but obtained without going into the log domain and back again.)

Comment: Heh - it was only through picking holes in your working that I saw there was a simpler method. ;-)